# How to determine dimension for basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5\}$ is a basis for $V$. Let $v_1,v_2,....,v_k$ be in $V$ such that $\text{span}\{v_1, v_2,....v_k\}=V$

Then $\text{span}\{(v_1)_B, (v_2)_B,....(v_k)_B\}= \mathbb R^n$

What is $n$?

Comment: Dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of its Basis. So here, $\dim(V)=5$.

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since B is basis for V and B contains 5 elements, dimension of V is 5.
$ Span \{v_1, v_2,...,v_k\} = V$ implies k is at least 5.

But each for $i$, $$ v_i = a_1\cdot u_1 +...+a_5\cdot u_5 $$ for some scalars $a_i$.
Hence linear combinations of $v_i$'s is same as $span(B)$ which is same as $V$ .
So $V = R^n$

So finally $n = 5$.

Comment: $(v_i)_B$ usually means the vector $v_i$ whose coordinates are described with respect to basis $B$ i.e. $(v_i)_B=[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5]$ if $v_i=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3+a_4u_4+a_5u_5$.